# Show progress of csv file iteration by letter, in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Python 3.9.5/Pandas 1.1.3

Somewhat new to programming in Python:

I use the following code to iterate over a csv file and use values from it to create and run queries in Elasticsearch, then write the results to a new csv file:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import pandas as pd

csv = "file.csv"
csv_file = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=",",
                       header=0, index_col=False)

client = Elasticsearch()
csv_output = "es_results.csv"
es_index = "main"
full_list = []
for index, row in csv_file.iterrows():
    institution_id = row["ID"]
    org_name_value = row['APPLICANT']
    query_body = {"an elasicsearch query"}         

    response = client.search(
        index=es_index,
        body=query_body)

    for hit in response['hits']['hits']:
        if hit['_score'] >= 0.9:
            result = institution_id, org_name_value, hit['_score']
            full_list.append(result)

df = pd.DataFrame(full_list)
df.to_csv(csv_output, index=False, header=['Institution_Id', 'Applicant_Name', 'Score'])
```

Some of this code is irrelevant to my question, but anytime I don't post my full code, I get asked to so that the reader has full context - you've been warned :)

The csv file that is iterated over has its `APPLICANT` column in alphabetical order.  What I want to do is print to the console when each letter is done being iterated over in the file, i.e.

```
"A is done",
"B is done",
"C is done"
```

Each letter of the alphabet has about 50k rows. Is the most efficient way to go about this by putting a `while` loop somewhere in my code, and using some combination of that and string index (`str.[0]`) against the `APPLICANT` column to get the first letter? If so, where would this code be placed?  I find the majority of my confusion with loops comes with where to properly place the levels (indentation).

Comment: does `print(org_name_value[0] + " is done")` work?

Comment: I don't see why you would need another loop since you're looping over the rows already - maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado you're likely not missing anything other than my own lack of experience :). Regarding your first suggestion of `print(org_name_value[0] + " is done")` - at what level would I place this?  Would this not just repeat over and over again until the given letter is actually done?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I just updated my question to clarify that each letter of the alphabet has about 50k entries.  Maybe that was confusing you.

Comment: oh! sorry yeah I had not caught that. is the data sorted alphabetically? that's also important. you could just create a variable `last_letter_processed` outside the for loop, start with assigning it None, and then include an if statement in your for loop to see if the letter has changed. every time it changes, print! then update with the new last_letter_processed.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado thanks, this is a great suggestion! I will try it!